# IQDropDownTextField inside UITableView CALayer invalid geometry error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, calayer

I have a UITableView with multiple cell containing IQDropDownTextField. When I reload the tableview, it crashes occasionally 1 out of 10. Here are my stack traces:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 nan; 320 291]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c3cd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010718321e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ca62b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   QuartzCore                          0x000000010561fc20 _ZN2CA5Layer10set_boundsERKNS_4RectEb + 230
    4   QuartzCore                          0x000000010561feb5 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 154
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001059e06c3 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 483
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000105a0caf3 -[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 1255
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105a9702b -[UITableView setBounds:] + 282
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001060e7eb1 -[UIPickerTableView setBounds:] + 120
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105a0d0d0 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 445
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000105a98092 -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 316
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001060e722b -[UIPickerTableView _setContentOffset:notify:] + 93
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105a26a7b -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _setContentOffset:animated:animationCurve:animationAdjustsForContentOffsetDelta:] + 957
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001060e63db -[UIPickerTableView _scrollRowAtIndexPathToSelectionBar:animated:] + 248
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001060e6764 -[UIPickerTableView selectRow:animated:notify:] + 755
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010591bb01 -[UIPickerView _selectRow:inComponent:animated:notify:] + 159
    16  FindAroundYou                       0x0000000102e08d46 -[IQDropDownTextField setSelectedRow:animated:] + 406
    17  FindAroundYou                       0x0000000102e08ba0 -[IQDropDownTextField setSelectedRow:] + 64
    18  FindAroundYou                       0x0000000102e09301 -[IQDropDownTextField setItemList:] + 161
    19  FindAroundYou                       0x0000000102e14a51 -[FAYHomeVC tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 2097
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa5584 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa57e2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000105a792b0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000105aaeb64 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000105a953be -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001059fcab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105629bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    27  QuartzCore                          0x000000010561d440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    28  QuartzCore                          0x000000010561d2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    29  QuartzCore                          0x00000001055ab318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    30  QuartzCore                          0x00000001055d83ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    31  QuartzCore                          0x00000001055d8d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107be1267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107be11d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107bc5f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107bc5884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ae1da6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000105937c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    38  FindAroundYou                       0x0000000102e2fd3f main + 111
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001081c768d start + 1
    40  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can someone please help me to figure out why this crash happening? I am not putting code because I don't know which part is causing this issue.